# Why are elifs not displaying when prompted? (PHP)

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I'm making a currency conversion website and it seems to work fine, but it only displays euros no matter option is chosen. For example, if I pick yen, it still shows Euros.

[[The website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeExm.png)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2da7P.png)

[Php Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqEDk.png)
[Html Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYCGv.png)

I tried to remedy this by editing the else-ifs and the if statement but still no luck.

HTML code

```
<html lang="en">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">   
   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Currency Converter</title>  
    <meta name="keywords" content="Currency Converter">
    <meta name="description" content="Currency Converter">
    <meta name="author" content="Currency Converter">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="convert.css"

</head>
<body class="host_version"> 

    <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
        
    <p><img src="images/currency.jpg" /></p>

<form action="convert2.php" method="post">

    <h3>Enter amount of U.S. dollar to convert:</h3>

    <input type="number" name="usdollar" min=".1" max="10000000000" step=".1"></p>

    <h3>Select unit to convert to:</h3>
    <label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="euro">Euro</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="ca">Canadian Dollar</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="yen">Japanese Yen</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="riyal">Qatari Riyal</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="rupee">Indian Rupee</label>
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td coldspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Convert"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code

```
<html lang="en">


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">   
   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
    <title>Currency Converter</title>  
    <meta name="keywords" content="Currency Converter">
    <meta name="description" content="Currency Converter">
    <meta name="author" content="Currency Converter">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="convert.css">

</head>
<body class="host_version"> 

    <!-- 3. Add content to h1 element -->
    <h1>Currency Converter</h1>

    <!-- 4. Add link to image -->
    <p><img src="images/currency.jpg" /></p>


<?php

    $choice = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'choice', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,1);
    $usdollar = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usdollar', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,2);
    $euro = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'euro', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,3);
    $ca = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ca', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,4);
    $yen = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'yen', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,5);
    $riyal = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'riyal', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,6);
    $rupee = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rupee', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,7);


    if ($choice == $euro)
        {
        $euro = ($usdollar * 0.91);
        echo "<p>$" . number_format($usdollar,2) ." USD is equal to ". number_format($euro,2) . " Euros.</p>";
        }

    elseif ($choice == $ca)
        {
        $ca = ($usdollar * 1.35);
        echo "<p>$" . number_format($usdollar,2) ." USD is equal to ". number_format($ca,2) . " Canadian Dollars.</p>";
        }

    elseif ($choice == $yen)
        {
        $yen = ($usdollar * 134.42);
        echo "<p>$" . number_format($usdollar,2) ." USD is equal to ". number_format($yen,2) . " Japanese Yen.</p>";
        }
        
    elseif ($choice == $riyal)
        {
        $riyal = ($usdollar * 3.64);
        echo "<p>$" . number_format($usdollar,2) ." USD is equal to ". number_format($riyal,2) . " Qatari Riyal.</p>";
        }

    elseif ($choice == $rupee)
        {
        $rupee = ($usdollar * 82.08);
        echo "<p>$" . number_format($usdollar,2) ." USD is equal to ". number_format($rupee,2) . " Indian Rupees.</p>";
        }
               
?>

    <!-- 6. Add button to go back to form -->

    <input type="button" value="Another Conversion" onclick="window.history.back()" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

(These are two separate files in the same folder)

Edited version with var_dump

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">   
   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
    <title>Currency Converter</title>  
    <meta name="keywords" content="Currency Converter">
    <meta name="description" content="Currency Converter">
    <meta name="author" content="Currency Converter">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="convert.css">

</head>
<body class="host_version"> 

    <!-- 3. Add content to h1 element -->
    <h1>Currency Converter</h1>

    <!-- 4. Add link to image -->
    <p><img src="images/currency.jpg" /></p>


<?php

    $choice = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'choice', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,1);
    $usdollar = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usdollar', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,2);
    $euro = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'euro', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,3);
    $ca = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ca', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,4);
    $yen = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'yen', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,5);
    $riyal = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'riyal', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,6);
    $rupee = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rupee', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,7);


    if (var_dump($choice) == 'euro')
        {
        $euro = ($usdollar * 0.91);
        echo "<p>$" . number_format($usdollar,2) ." USD is equal to ". number_format($euro,2) . " Euros.</p>";
        }

    elseif (var_dump($choice) == 'ca')
        {
        $ca = ($usdollar * 1.35);
        echo "<p>$" . number_format($usdollar,2) ." USD is equal to ". number_format($ca,2) . " Canadian Dollars.</p>";
        }

    elseif (var_dump($choice) == 'yen')
        {
        $yen = ($usdollar * 134.42);
        echo "<p>$" . number_format($usdollar,2) ." USD is equal to ". number_format($yen,2) . " Japanese Yen.</p>";
        }
        
    elseif (var_dump($choice) == 'riyal')
        {
        $riyal = ($usdollar * 3.64);
        echo "<p>$" . number_format($usdollar,2) ." USD is equal to ". number_format($riyal,2) . " Qatari Riyal.</p>";
        }

    elseif (var_dump($choice) == 'rupee')
        {
        $rupee = ($usdollar * 82.08);
        echo "<p>$" . number_format($usdollar,2) ." USD is equal to ". number_format($rupee,2) . " Indian Rupees.</p>";
        }
               
?>

    <!-- 6. Add button to go back to form -->

    <input type="button" value="Another Conversion" onclick="window.history.back()" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: None of the `FILTER_POST` calls for radio button values are correct. Those are all just values of the `choice` input. You should be comparing with literals, like `if ($choice == 'usdollar')`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for replying, I tried changing them but now there's nothing being displayed at all when I press convert. (I.E I turned if ($choice == $euro) into  if ($choice == 'euro')

Comment: What does `var_dump($choice)` show?

Comment: @Barmar where should I paste it?

Comment: After you assign the variable.

Comment: @Barmar I added it, now it's displaying:

"string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" "

Comment: Why are you getting 5 outputs for one variable?

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure. I'll edit the code above and show you what I did

Comment: Why are you using `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` for `$choice`? Its value is a string, not a number.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I'm still learning the ins and outs of php. I tried changing it again, this time to ```FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING``` but it's now giving me  "string(1) "" string(1) "" string(1) "" string(1) "" string(1) "" "

Answer (score 2):

`$choice` is not an integer, you shouldn't use `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`. Just use the value of the `$_POST` variable.

Then compare it with literal strings, you shouldn't use other calls to `filter_input()` for the different options.

You shouldn't use `substr()` when setting `$usdollar`. Your input allows it to be very large, you shouldn't use just the first 2 characters.

```
$usdollar =     $usdollar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usdollar', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$choice = $_POST['choice'];

if ($choice == 'euro') {
    ...
} elseif ($choice == 'ca') {
    ...
} elseif ($choice == 'yen') {
    ...
```

and so on.